# Does Dojo provide Heatmap charts?

Tags: charts, dojo, heatmap

**What's required:**

- Heatmap charts by Dojo to show data in 2-D chart as colored cells for MVC.NET project.
- Eg., Something similar to these [Plotly heatmaps](https://plot.ly/javascript/heatmaps/)
- **Platform**: IE
- **Features**: Annotations, Zooming, Interactive, text rotation for labels, dynamic chart.

**What's researched:**

- Dojo ticket [11705](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11705) asking for Heatmap. But was closed as 'wontfix'.
- Found a patch intermediately shared for above ticket. But, it did not work.

If the Heatmaps are not currently supported, are there future plans to include it?

Comment: I dont know if that could help you , but there is a dojo based lib for GIS that has heatmap api [heat map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/heatmaprenderer-amd.html)

Comment: I'm not exactly looking for a GIS based heatmap. I need to product something like this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Wafermap.jpg using Dojo. 
Thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no a heat-map chart ready made in dojo, but you could develop you own combining its functionalities.

Could be of interest:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/charting.html

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/gfx.html